# unsafe.compareAndSwapInt first argument menanig

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, atomic-swap

I am investigating `java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`source code.

From severals place invokes `compareAndSetState` method.

```
/**
 * Atomically sets synchronization state to the given updated
 * value if the current state value equals the expected value.
 * This operation has memory semantics of a {@code volatile} read
 * and write.
 *
 * @param expect the expected value
 * @param update the new value
 * @return {@code true} if successful. False return indicates that the actual
 *         value was not equal to the expected value.
 */
protected final boolean compareAndSetState(int expect, int update) {
    // See below for intrinsics setup to support this
    return unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(this, stateOffset, expect, update);
}
```

Parameters  `expect` and `update` are obvious and correspond the atomics parameters. But `this` is Object(rather than `int`).
How does this compares with expect?

Answer (score 1):

It's the instance whose field `state` will be CAS-ed. The value is stored in that field. The instance-offset pair is a way to translate the field descriptor to a memory address, just like you need to supply the instance when using `Field::set`, `Field::get` or `Method::invoke`.

Btw, these sun classes' source is available online at [openjdk's mercury repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#l882).

Comment: How AbstractQueuedSynchronizer can have value?

Comment: It's the `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer::state` field, not the object itself.

Comment: *The instance-offset pair* what is it?

Comment: It's the first and the second function parameter.